# Unable to see/create folder for some activities in Automation Studio Activities page

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does anyone know why I am unable to create folder for some activities.
In the screenshot, I am able to create folder for "SQL Query" activity but unable to create folder for "Data Extract" activity.

[image: Able to see create folder option for SQL Query activity]
[image: Unable to see the create folder option for Data Extract activity]

Comment: Hi, I tried to toggle around within the platform, googling and search in stack exchange, but couldn't find the answer, hence, I create this post. Can anyone share why this post deserves -1 point? thanks.

Comment: That is expected behavior unfortunately (not documented) but likely something left over from the days of Exact Target and how they laid the foundation of this capability.

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington for the reply.